# Add a negative price line item or discount

Tags: authorize.net

I'm using coupons in a storefront to offer discounts. Some coupons are for a flat dollar amount for orders greater than a specific value. Like, $10 off an order of $40 or more. Other coupons give a discounted rate, say, 20% off your first order this month (storefront is handling the limit, so can ignore). I want to use authorize.net to process the transactions, and send receipts to customers.

My first thought was to modify the unit price of things that are discounted. This would work fine for rate discounts, though doesn't show all the information. The problem would be for flat discounts. Where do you take the $10 off if there are a few kinds of items.

My second thought was to add a line item with a negative value/price to the order receipt. Authorize doesn't seem to accept negative values for anything, so that was a failure.

We're using the AIM transaction libraries for Java.

```
Order anetOrder = Order.createOrder();
anetOrder.setInvoiceNumber(sanitize(order.getOrderNumber(), 20));
anetOrder.setShippingCharges(shippingCharges);
anetOrder.setTotalAmount(total);

for (OrderProductIf op : order.getOrderProducts()) {
    OrderItem item = OrderItem.createOrderItem();
    item.setItemTaxable(true);
    item.setItemId(sanitize(op.getSku(), 31));
    item.setItemName(sanitize(op.getName(), 31));
    item.setItemDescription(sanitize(op.getModel(), 255));
    item.setItemPrice(op.getPrice());
    item.setItemQuantity(new BigDecimal(op.getQuantity()));

    anetOrder.addOrderItem(item);
}
```

sanitize is a function that limits the length of strings.

```
Transaction transaction = merchant.createAIMTransaction(TransactionType.AUTH_CAPTURE, total);
transaction.setCreditCard(creditCard);
transaction.setCustomer(customer);
transaction.setOrder(anetOrder);
transaction.setShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
transaction.setShippingCharges(shippingCharges);

Result<Transaction> result = (Result<Transaction>) merchant.postTransaction(transaction);
return getPaymentResult(result);
```

I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Even though you may be using Java as part of your project, please do not use the `java` tag unless your question is actually about Java itself.

Comment: You might just want to send your receipt so you can customize it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to calculate the total amount with the discount without modifying the line items, for a $60 sale with a $10 discount below:

```
<transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>50</amount>
```

Then add

```
<userFields>
      <userField>
        <name>Discount</name>
        <value>$10.00</value>
      </userField>
```

The userField value is arbitrary, make it -$10.00, if you like it better.

Comment: Without the negative indicator some users may be confused by this.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise with my question, we're using AIM in this legacy system. Are userFields only for the new API?

Comment: The AIM method had Merchant defined fields which would be like the UserFields in the new API.

Answer (score 0):

The line items are not totaled. SO

- Add line item for credit in your system.
- When you submit to Authorize.net, check for negative numbers and change description to indicate it is a credit, then change value to positive
- Make sure the TOTAL you submit is correct.  Authorize.net will not check that your line items add up to the correct total